# Is there a MySQL character set and encoding that will allow for both emojis and accents?

Tags: mysql, collation, character-set, encoding

I've got a database of terms that get added to by one group of users, and queried against by another.

I was running into problems when people would query for an emoji in the database and my React app would throw an error (oddly a CORS error, but that's a different issue). I eventually solved this by changing my table's character set to `utf8mb4` with `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` collation.

Now I'm getting errors when adding new terms saying, for example, that a duplicate row for "beyoncé" already exists. However, when I query the db for "beyoncé", it returns the row with "beyonce" in it. Is there a combination of charset and collation that can handle this properly?

My DB is MySQL 5.6.40 running on Amazon RDS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I was running into problems when people would query for an emoji in the database and my React app would throw an error

What was the exact error message? What were the character set and collation of the column before you changed it to `utfmb4` and `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`? In MySQL, collation can be set at many levels, including the client connection.

That said, Unicode (`utf8` being one of the Unicode encodings), supports all characters. If your character set truly is `utf8mb4`, then there is no need to change that.

You said:

> I'm getting errors when adding new terms saying for example that a duplicate row for "beyoncé" already exists, however when I query the db for "beyoncé", it returns the row with "beyonce" in it.

The [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/charset-collation-names.html) states:

> For nonbinary collation names that do not specify accent sensitivity, it is determined by case sensitivity. If a collation name does not contain `_ai` or `_as`, `_ci` in the name implies `_ai` and `_cs` in the name implies `_as`.

So, since your collation is `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`, then it is both case-insensitive *and* accent-insensitive. And this is why "beyoncé" matches "beyonce".

If you need "beyoncé" and "beyonce" to be considered different, then ideally you would use a case-sensitive (and either explicitly-stated or implied accent-sensitive) collation. However, it looks like this is not available in MySQL 5.6 (or even 5.7), while MySQL 8.0 does have `utf8mb4_0900_as_cs`, or even `utf8mb4_0900_as_ci` if you only want the accent to distinguish between the values while allowing "beyonce" and "Beyonce" to match.

So for now, it looks like you might need to use a binary collation, `utf8mb4_bin`, either by changing the collation of the column, or by adding `COLLATE utf8mb4_bin` to one or more queries.

Comment: I think you need at least `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci` to treat Emoji as different from each other.